rc. local not working
I have an issue with opening Python script at startup.
I have added python /home/serhii/Desktop/Packed/Hello.py & to rc.local and the script does not open. But, the command sudo pigpiod is working.
Same with crotab
What could be wrong? Any advice?

See Tour to see how this site works
and How do I ask a good question?
